# How to save escaped symbols &quot; after parsing and saving xml file via java dom

Tags: java, xml, escaping

For example I have an input.xml file with next content:

```
<root>&quot;Hello World!&quot;</root>
```

Then I read it and parse:

```
// parse xml file
DocumentBuilderFactory factory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("input.xml"));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Suppose i just want to save it in other place:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();    
Result output = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"));           
        doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
        Source input = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.transform(input, output);
```

And I get output.xml file :

```
<root>"Hello World!"</root>
```

What i need to do to avoid this replacement?
I have not found any solution anywhere.

Comment: use cdata to store that particular data

Comment: Could you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [Is there a Java XML API that can parse a document without resolving character entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777878/is-there-a-java-xml-api-that-can-parse-a-document-without-resolving-character-en) and [Java XML Parsing: Avoid entity reference resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240857/java-xml-parsing-avoid-entity-reference-resolution)

If you want to keep `entity reference`, you need a special XML parser.

Comment: Thanks.[This](http://sourceforge.net/p/commonclasses/code/14/tree/trunk/src/com/redhat/ecs/commonutils/XMLUtilities.java) with small corrections finally have solved my problem.